What is this fuzzy artifact?
I'm trying to understand what is causing the fuzzy white distortion in my render (see edges of arch & star streaks). I've tried various smoothing and anti-aliasing settings but no luck. I'm a beginner though so I might be on the wrong track.
Any suggestions?



You can try rendering with more samples or, if that doesn't help, attach a .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com

i hope you don't mean the reflection? can you please make some annotations what you mean? if you mean the reflection-> turn down your light strength which is behind the model i assume (or your hdri)

I thought the same as @Chris here, it seems you mean the reflections? Maybe not only from the light behind but also the "star streaks". Are those artifacts there when you disable the streaks or the background light? Then probably the only thing I can suggest is using more samples as KISKAart already mentioned and denoising...

are you talking about the Bloom effect?

Added another image. I'm referring to the grainy/sandy look to the way the light hits the edges of the arches, and the similar thing happening with the star streaks.

This looks like your samples count is too low, as KISKAart suggested.

Ok will give that a go. Thanks!
